# Angular 2 using third party libraries in template

Tags: angular, justgage

I'm trying to use a third party (JustGage) in my application
I've loaded it correctly in the angular-cli.json file
and im able to instanciate it like this in my component

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    var g = new JustGage({
      id: "gauge",
      value: 67,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      title: "System Health"
    });
}
```

this actually works nice but i noticed my IDE complaining about

> Cannot find name 'JustGage'

When i tried to build the application the compilation failed due to this error.

How do i solved this issue?

BTW i tried declaring a JustGage: any
and then call this.JustGage , but the gauge is not rendered and the console 
UPDATE

```
declare var require: any;
var JustGage = require("justgage/justgage.js");
```

So the require brings something but its not the JustGage
says that JustGage is not a constructor...

Comment: try adding the script to your index.html and then in your code at the very top type: declare let JustGage:any

Comment: I'm using the angular-cli and it loads the files correctly, the problem is typescript one

Comment: Since you are using webpack you should be able to include it at the top of your .ts file `import * as JustGage from 'JustGage';`. If that doesn't work you might need to fiddle with your loaders in your webpack.config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so since it was already working the issue was not the actual usage of the third party library but a typescript issue
it was solved by

```
declare var JustGage: any;
```

in the import section
after that i was able to compile

just in case it helps someone, thew actual loading of the scripts is done in the angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
    "../node_modules/justgage/raphael-2.1.4.min.js",
    "../node_modules/justgage/justgage.js"
  ],
```

Comment: You might be able to compile, but does webpack bundle and load it correctly as well? You should put the JustGage dependency in your vendor file and import it using an import statement instead.

Comment: @patrick i configured the angular-cli.json to load the needed scripts

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access that `JustGage` library you will have to either `import` it if you're using es6 syntax or `require` it otherwise.

Using the name like this means you're assuming that is a `global variable`.

```
import {JustGage} from 'path/JustGage'
```

Or you can put this line in your file (supposing you're using typescript, otherwise change the extension to whatever you want):

```
/// <reference path="path/JustGage.d.ts" />
```

And of course you will have to reference your lib somewhere in your `index.html` or `config`.

Comment: cannot find module 'justgage', this library doesn't export

Comment: also out of luck with require constructor() {
    this.JustGage = this.require("justgage/justgage.js");
  } // this.require is not a function

Comment: Ah require is not on this and it shouldn't be called within constuctor. That goes on top of your file, but before getting there I need to know what packaging tool you are using @naoru

Comment: its angular-cli

Comment: angular-cli uses webpack

Comment: do you have a vendor file as well, how are you bundling your 3rd party libs? @naoru